# Android Unique installation and license

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

I want to create device specific login in android mobile application,so that one license for one mobile user can be achieved(limit the installation for 1 device).

I have used **android id** but it changed after **factory reset**.MAC address and IMEI Not available in higher android versions. UUID can not be stored into private Storage as it can be tampered with rooted device.

How can I create device specific login and if I want to use unique key for the same which key should I use ?

Comment: You can't, at least not reliably. There's a good argument to be made that after a factory reset, it's really a new device. Also, you might want to rethink your approach. The Android model is that apps are licensed to the user, not to the device. Do you really want to tell your users that they no longer have a license for the app if they have to replace their device?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play offers a way to restrict devices: Use the License Verification Library and [implement a `DeviceLimiter`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html#impl-DeviceLimiter). I found [the interface](https://github.com/ishida/android-easy-lvl/blob/master/LicenseVerificationLibrary/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/DeviceLimiter.java) and it has some documentation:

> The LICENSED response from the server contains a user identifier unique to
>   the <application, user> pair. The developer can send this identifier
>   to their own server along with some device identifier (a random number
>   generated and stored once per application installation,
>   {@link android.telephony.TelephonyManager#getDeviceId getDeviceId},
>   {@link android.provider.Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID ANDROID_ID}, etc).
>   The more sources used to identify the device, the harder it will be for an
>   attacker to spoof.